# Centering Block Elements

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists, block

First, I'll start off by saying that I do not have control over the HTML and this is what the HTML looks like:

```
<ul class="orbit-bullets">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Second note I'll put is that I wouldn't mind using `inline-block`, but I need a fallback for non-supportive browsers.

I am trying to center the list. The list items must display inline but they must be block elements because I'm declaring a width, height and text-indent. So I know that I can use `display:block; float:left;`, but I would like the elements to be centered. And sometimes there are three list items or four or more, so I do not want to set a fixed width on the unordered list smaller than 500px. If I set the width to 500px, when there are just two or three list items, they appear very off centered.

**I need to center the list items themselves within the unordered list while still using `display:block; float:left;`.** 
 Or is there a way to have a variable width on the unordered list while still having it centered? I'm up to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: How about ul {display :block;margin :auto}

Comment: @Sam I would need to declare the width for that...

Comment: @Ateszki I would need to declare the width for that...

Comment: It can help if you set a fixed width, and auto margin for "ul". And centered text for "li" items. What you want is hard without being able to modify html.

Comment: @Firula I can't center the text for `<li>` elements since they are floating to the left.

Comment: I know you can't modify html, but is there any chance to include a javascript in head section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one - http://jsfiddle.net/jD6yp/

```
ul {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background: beige;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;

    zoom: 1;          /* for old IE-s */
    *display: inline; /* for old IE-s */

    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

Comment: The `<li>`s must be block elements because I'm declaring a width, height and text-indent.

Comment: I'm talking about the non-inline-block-supporting browsers, I don't think the fall back is the best one possible.

Comment: I've tried the code in IE7 and IE6 - it was OK with all the margins and paddings, so I tend to believe that height and width will also work